# Particle system won't collide with box collider all the time. Rain seeps through ceiling

Tags: unity, collision-detection, particles, graphic-effects, weather

I'm trying to make it rain in my game, but am having a problem with it seeping through the ceiling. I put a box collider above the house to catch the rain as it falls and it worked for a while, but stopped working suddenly. I'm unsure of the cause of this at the moment. I have tried to change some variables in the particle system and tried other box colliders to test out different approaches, but nothing seems to be working. I am pushing a lot of particles for the rain system being about 2500 at any given time, but its not slowing down the gameplay at all. Could it just be too much for the system to process at a time? Below is a few images of my setup.
[image: House Roof Collider]

[image: Rain Particle System]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in your screenshot, the Particle System's [Collision Module](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PartSysCollisionModule.html) has a property ["Max Collision Shapes"](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.CollisionModule-maxCollisionShapes.html) which is currently set to 256. This means that only 256 rain particles will have colliders. If you have 2500 particles, most of them will not have colliders.

You can try increasing the value to 2500, but you may need to reduce the Collision Quality to prevent performance issues.

Comment: Ah. I see. Ill give that a shot. Thank you. Let you know how it goes.

Comment: That was the solution. Fortunately I am still able to keep the game running at the same quality without performance issues at this time. Hopefully the same holds true in the future as well.

Comment: If you do end up suffering from performance issues. You can always just load the rain around the player for example. So that way theres never a ton of particles at once and it stays consistent.

Comment: @WestMansionHero Great! Please don't forget to mark this answer as the correct answer.